# Mouse and keyboard slow to recognize with KVM switch

Tags: keyboard, usb, mouse

I recently started using a KVM switch, so that I can share my usb mouse and keyboard between my linux and windows notebooks, when working at my desk.  My windows machine handles the switch seamlessly, whereas my ubuntu system takes 5-10 seconds to re-recognize the mouse and keyboard.

Is there some way I can speed this up?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat on a different track, but possibly a good solution for your problem, is [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/). It's a free, open-source, cross-platform piece of software (that means it can work on both of your machines and more) which allows you to switch the keyboard and mouse input from one machine to another just by moving your mouse. It creates a seamless experience: you just move the mouse to the screen you want to be on and the keyboard focus changes automatically. It works over your network, so that would be basically its only requirement.